# Elasticsearch date_histogram with interval shows incorrect dates

Tags: elasticsearch, histogram, aggregation, date-histogram

I use **date_histogram** aggregation from Elasticsearch with interval of **2d** and I also have a filter for one month. eg. from 2019-11-01 to 2019-11-31.

I have a mapping like this:

```
PUT test_index/test/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "date": {
      "type": "date",
      "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
    }
  }
}
```

Then I insert data like this:

```
POST test_index/test
{
  "date": "2019-11-01", 
  "content": "hello world!"
}

POST test_index/test
{
  "date": "2019-11-02", 
  "content": "hello world!"
}

POST test_index/test
{
  "date": "2019-11-03", 
  "content": "hello world!"
}
```

Following is my query:

```
GET test_index/test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "histogram": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "date": {
            "gte": "2019-11-01",
            "lte": "2019-11-30"
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "my_histogram": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "date",
            "interval": "2d"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get this result:

```
{
  ...
  "aggregations" : {
    "histogram" : {
      "meta" : { },
      "doc_count" : 3,
      "my_histogram" : {
        "buckets" : [
          {
            "key_as_string" : "2019-10-31",
            "key" : 1572480000000,
            "doc_count" : 1
          },
          {
            "key_as_string" : "2019-11-02",
            "key" : 1572652800000,
            "doc_count" : 2
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get the first bucket with key **2019-10-31**.

I would like to get the result starting from **2019-11-01**.

Can you guys help me out, please?

I am using Elasticsearch 6.6.1.

Comment: What happens when you take 1 day interval?

Comment: It starts from “2019-11-01”

Comment: And which timezone are you in?

Comment: Myanmar, GMT+6:30

Comment: What happens if you add `"time_zone": "+06:30"` to your date histogram aggregation?

Comment: The result is the same.

Comment: Can you show a sample document and the mapping of the `date` field please?

Comment: {
  "date": "2019-11-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "content": "some text here"
}

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue on ES 7.4

Comment: could you please test on other months? because it didn't happen on Oct in my case.

Comment: You need to provide us with a way of reproducing your test. Create the index + index two documents and the search query which shows the actual vs expected results

Comment: first I do mapping for date field

PUT test_index/test/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "date": {
      "type": "date",
      "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
    }
  }
}

then I insert a document each day from **2019-11-01** to **2019-11-03**

POST test_index/test
{
  "date": "2019-11-03",  -> 01 to 03
  "content": "hello world!"
}

Comment: Update your question, it's more legible than in comments

Comment: I have updated my question. Thanks.

Comment: So your date doesn't look like you said earlier `2019-11-01T00:00:00.000Z` right?

Comment: ah. yeah. sorry

Comment: Hi @Val, btw, did you use the fixed interval or calendar interval?